# React email validation error not displaying

Tags: reactjs, regex, email

I am using React-typescript for my app. I have created one form where, there are three input fields `email` `password` and `confirm-password`. After submit the form I want to catch the error and want to display to the browser. i successfully implement the password error, when the password did not match I can able to display the error.I used same method for email validation but it does not display the error. For email validation I have created function where I used `regex`(I have two `regex` validator, their functionality is ok). but i don't why my `error state does not catch the error`

I share my code in [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/email-validation-95c57?file=/src/App.tsx).

**This is my input form**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextInput } from "./input";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: ``,
    password: ``,
    passwordConfirmation: ``,
    loading: false,
    accountCreationSuccessful: false,
    errorPasswrodMessage: ``,
    errorEmailMessage: ``
  });
  const {
    loading,
    password,
    passwordConfirmation,
    email,
    errorPasswrodMessage,
    errorEmailMessage
  } = state;

  // regex valid
  const isValidEmail = (value: any) => {
    const expreg = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

    if (value.length > 0) {
      if (!expreg.test(value)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };

  // regex
  const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  console.log(isValidEmail(email)); // by default its true if user put wrong email they it will be false
  const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setState({
      ...state,
      loading: true
    });
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://run.mocky.io/v3/03659a5b-fed5-4c5f-b8d0-4b277e902ed3",
      {
        method: `POST`,
        headers: {
          Accept: `application/json`,
          "Content-Type": `application/json`
        },
        body: { state }
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        accountCreationSuccessful: true,
        email: ``,
        password: ``,
        passwordConfirmation: ``
      });
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }

    console.log(email);
    console.log(isValidEmail(email));
    if (password !== passwordConfirmation) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        errorPasswrodMessage: `Upps sorry Password did not match `
      });
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      //alert("error");
      setState({
        ...state,
        "errorEmailMessage ": `Upps sorry wrong email  `
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="email"
        label="Email"
        required
        error={errorEmailMessage}
      />
      <TextInput
        type="password"
        value={state.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="password"
        required
        label="password"
        isPassword
        error={errorPasswrodMessage}
      />
      <TextInput
        type="password"
        value={state.passwordConfirmation}
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="passwordConfirmation"
        required
        label="Confirm password"
        isPassword
        error={errorPasswrodMessage}
      />
      <button type="submit" name="action" onClick={onSubmit} disabled={!email}>
        {loading ? `loading...` : `save`}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This is my input base**

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export interface Props {
  value: string;
  onChange: (e: string) => void;
  error?: string;
  id?: string;
  type?: "text" | "number" | "password" | "email";
  isPassword?: boolean;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  onBlur?: () => void;
  onFocus?: () => void;
  label?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  description?: string;

  placeholder?: string;
}

export const TextInput = memo(
  ({
    value,
    onChange,
    id,
    type,
    style,
    label,
    required,
    description,
    error,
    placeholder
  }: Props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Label>
            {label} {required && <span style={{ color: `red` }}> *</span>}
          </Label>
          <Input
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            id={id}
            type={type}
            style={style}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </Container>
        {description && <Description>{description}</Description>}
        {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
      </div>
    );
  }
);
const Input = styled.input`
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px 0px;
`;

const Label = styled.label`
  display: inline-block;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;

const Error = styled.p`
  color: red;
`;

const Description = styled.p`
  color: blue;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check the whole code but have a typo in setState.

```
else if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
  //alert("error");
  setState({
    ...state,
    "errorEmailMessage ": `Upps sorry wrong email  `
 });
```

This will fix your issue.

```
setState({
  ...state,
  errorEmailMessage: `Upps sorry wrong email  `
});
```

Comment: Sorry mate. it did not work. I have elsint setup. it creats automatic string, if there is object.

Comment: Hangon a second. it actually works :D.

Comment: Just one question: do you have any clue how to display all error at a same time. if user put wrong email and password does not confirm.
Thanks for the help btw 

Comment: You have two different regexes that check the email, why?

Comment: @krisna
There is plenty of things that need to be adjusted.
First of all the validation has to be done before you are sending the request.
And if you have to show both errors, replace `else if` statement with `if statement`.

And if the errors exist don't call the API, just execute `return`.
I'll paste a snippet with an example.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/email-validation-forked-jnbii?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.tsx

I cleaned the code a little bit, then you can see how it should be handled.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learnt a lot from you.